# Method to display records.

Tags: java

Hey guys just need help on how to finish this up.

*Code Snippet:*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateLoans implements LoanConstants {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //set the program here
        float prime;
        float amountOfLoan = 0;
        String customerFirstName;
        String customerLastName;
        String LoanType;


        System.out.println("Please Enter the current prime interest rate");
        prime = sc.nextInt() / 100f;

        //ask for Personal or Business
        System.out.println("are you after a business or personal loan? Type business or personal");
        LoanType = sc.next();

        //enter the Loan amount
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of loan");
        amountOfLoan = sc.nextInt();

        //enter Customer Names  
        System.out.println("Enter First Name");
        customerFirstName = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
        customerLastName = sc.next();

        //enter the term
        System.out.println("Enter the Type of Loan you want. 1 = short tem , 2 = medium term , 3 = long term");
        int t = sc.nextInt();


    }
}
```

I need to display the records I have asked and store the object into an array.

so this where I'm stuck. I need to do this in a loop 5 times and by the end display all records in an array, if that makes sense?

Comment: Have to attempted it? Do you now know how to write a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way :

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CreateLoans {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Loan[] loans = new Loan[5];

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            loans[i] = new Loan();
            System.out.println("Please Enter the current prime interest rate");
            float prime = sc.nextInt();
            prime = (float)(prime/100f);
            loans[i].setPrime(prime);


            //ask for Personal or Business
            System.out.println("are you after a business or personal loan? Type business or personal");
            String loanType = sc.next();
            loans[i].setLoanType(loanType);

            //enter the Loan amount
            System.out.println("Enter the amount of loan");
            float amountOfLoan = sc.nextFloat();
            loans[i].setAmountOfLoan(amountOfLoan);

            //enter Customer Names  
            System.out.println("Enter First Name");
            String customerFirstName = sc.next();
            loans[i].setCustomerFirstName(customerFirstName);

            System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
            String customerLastName = sc.next();
            loans[i].setCustomerLastName(customerLastName);
        }

        //Display details 

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            System.out.println(loans[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Loan {
    private float prime;
    private float amountOfLoan = 0;
    private String customerFirstName;
    private String customerLastName;
    private String LoanType;
    public float getPrime() {
        return prime;
    }
    public void setPrime(float prime) {
        this.prime = prime;
    }
    public float getAmountOfLoan() {
        return amountOfLoan;
    }
    public void setAmountOfLoan(float amountOfLoan) {
        this.amountOfLoan = amountOfLoan;
    }
    public String getCustomerFirstName() {
        return customerFirstName;
    }
    public void setCustomerFirstName(String customerFirstName) {
        this.customerFirstName = customerFirstName;
    }
    public String getCustomerLastName() {
        return customerLastName;
    }
    public void setCustomerLastName(String customerLastName) {
        this.customerLastName = customerLastName;
    }
    public String getLoanType() {
        return LoanType;
    }
    public void setLoanType(String loanType) {
        LoanType = loanType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "First Name : " + customerFirstName + "\n" +
               "Last Name : " + customerLastName + "\n" +
               "Amount of Loan : " + amountOfLoan + "\n" +
               "Loan type : " + LoanType + "\n" +
               "Prime : " + prime + "\n\n"; 
    }
}
```

Create a Loan class and put all necessary details as private members into it and override toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `ArrayList` and add all the variables inside that list

```
ArrayList arrlist = new ArrayList();
arrlist.add(prime);
arrlist.add(LoanType);
arrlist.add(amountOfLoan);
arrlist.add(customerFirstName );
arrlist.add(customerLastName);
arrlist.add(t);
```

and display the `ArrayList`

```
System.out.println(arrlist);
```

Comment: Can you please, 1/ don't use raw types, 2/ use interface for variable type when possible?

Answer (score 0):

Example of a loop

```
int[] nums = new int[5];
String[] names = new String[5];

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    // insert into array
    nums[i] = number;

    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
    String name = input.nextLne();

    // insert into array
    names[i] = name;

}
```

Everything you want to be looped 5 times, you can put inside the loop. Whatever values you want to store, you can do that in the loop also.